# Completion Block Not Executing

Tags: objective-c, ios, core-data, block

Here is the call with the block:

```
[VacationHelper openVacationWithName:vacationName
                usingBlock:^(UIManagedDocument *vacationDocument) {
   NSLog(@"vacationDocument.description:%@", vacationDocument.description);
}];
```

In the receiving method's .h:

```
typedef void (^completion_block_t)(UIManagedDocument *vacationDocument);
```

And in the .m:

```
+ (void)openVacationWithName:(NSString *)vacationName
                  usingBlock:(completion_block_t)completionBlock;
{
    NSLog(@"Opening Vacation Document");

    // Get documents directory and path.
    NSURL *url = [[[NSFileManager defaultManager] URLsForDirectory:NSDocumentDirectory inDomains:NSUserDomainMask] lastObject];
    url        = [url URLByAppendingPathComponent:vacationName];

    // Create the document and open if a match exists on file.
    UIManagedDocument *vacationDocument = [[UIManagedDocument alloc] initWithFileURL:url];
    if ([[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:[url path]]) {
        NSLog(@"vacationDocument.documentState:%i", vacationDocument.documentState);
        [vacationDocument openWithCompletionHandler:^(BOOL success) {
            if (success) NSLog(@"Document was opened.");
            else NSLog (@"Couldn't open document at %@", url);
        }];
    } else {

        // No match exists, so save the document to file.
        [vacationDocument saveToURL:url forSaveOperation:UIDocumentSaveForCreating
                  completionHandler:^(BOOL success) {
                      if (success) NSLog(@"Document was created.");
                      else NSLog(@"Couldn't create document at %@", url);
                  }];
    }
    NSLog(@"Exiting helper.");
}
```

My question is why does execution not reach the block passed in the call to `openVacationWithName:`?  I never see the NSLog written.

I suspect that `openVacationWithName:` doesn't finish, but the NSLog for "Exiting helper." does print.  Any guidance appreciated.  FYI this is for iTunes U/Stanford CS193P assignment #6.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're not calling `completionBlock` inside `openVacationWithName:usingBlock:`. Maybe you'd like to do it at the end of the method:

```
  ...
  if (completionBlock) {
    completionBlock(vacationDocument);
  }

  NSLog(@"Exiting helper.");
}
```

(in this case, maybe it would make more sense to just return the `UIManagedDocument`)

Or maybe inside those `completionHandler`s in methods `openWithCompletionHandler:` and `saveToUrl:forSaveOperation:completionHandler:`:

```
... ^(BOOL success) {
  if (success) {
    NSLog(@"Document was created.");
  }
  else {
    NSLog(@"Couldn't create document at %@", url);
  }

  if (completionBlock) {
    completionBlock(vacationDocument);
  }
} ...
```

Comment: Thank you, Jordão. I had assumed that the passed block would execute automatically once the called method was completed.  Inserting a call as you mentioned above worked. ...
  completionBlock(vacationDocument);
  NSLog(@"Exiting helper.");

Comment: I want to mention here about good practice, the wrap block calls in if statement: `if (block) block();`, so your function can be called with nil completion handler without exceptions.

Comment: Thanks @kelin, you're absolutely right and I'll change the code accordingly.